# Expected Value of Triangle Area

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question.** Suppose we have the triangle with sides $W$ and $W+1$, where $W$ is a random variable (what type of random variable is not specified). Find the expected value of the area of the triangle.

**My Idea:** We can let $W \sim \text{Uniform}(\alpha, \beta)$ and $X = W+1$. Then to find the area or a triangle we need to find $E[.5WX]$. Thus,

$$
\begin{align}
E[.5WX] &= .5E[WX] \\
&= .5 \int_\alpha^\beta \int_\alpha^{w+1} wx \cdot f(w,x) dxdw.
\end{align}
$$

But I'm not entirely sure how $f(w,x)$ would be defined in this case (I do know $f(w) = \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha}$ for $\alpha < w < \beta$ and $0$ o/w) and if my bounds are correct, or even if this is a proper way to go about solving.

Comment: A triangle have 3 sides, what is the length of third side?

Comment: Not given. Supposedly, we can find the expected area w/o it. Typo in question maybe?

Comment: If it is not given, then the only way to proceed is assume the triangle is a right angled one. In that case, you are using the right formula for area. However, once the value of $W$ is known, so does the value of $X = W+1$, $x$ doesn't have a separate probability distribution from $w$. The correct formula for expected value is $\frac12 \int f(w) w(w+1) dw$ instead.

Comment: When you get the solution to this question (I'm guessing this is assigned work, so presumably you will have a solution when your homework is returned), please locate the information that was assumed by the asker but not stated above, and update your question with it.

Comment: PS: We cannot just *let* the distribution be uniform, since the type is not specified.  We need to leave it abstract.  The only thing we can assume is that side length $W$ is a non-negative real number.